# How to use ConvLSTM2D followed by Conv2D in Keras python

Tags: python, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I am trying to use the following model in Keras, where `ConvLSTM2D` output is followed by  `Conv2D` to generate segmentation-like output. Input and output should be time series of the size `(2*WINDOW_H+1, 2*WINDOW_W+1)` each

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(3, kernel_size=3, padding = "same", batch_input_shape=(1, None, 2*WINDOW_H+1, 2*WINDOW_W+1, 1), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
model.add(Conv2D(1, kernel_size=3, padding = "same"))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

However, this gives the following error (when adding Conv2D):

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5
```

Any pointers on where I might be wrong really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to do a time distributed Conv2D layer so that the dimensions match. Like this maybe:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(3, kernel_size=3, padding = "same", batch_input_shape=(1, None, 2*WINDOW_H+1, 2*WINDOW_W+1, 1), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed((Conv2D(1, kernel_size=3, padding = "same")))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your model that you try to use the sequence for the regular convolutional layer.
The only thing that you need is to remove `return_sequences=True` in `ConvLSTM2D`.

So this line:

```
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(3, kernel_size=3, padding = "same", batch_input_shape=(1, None, 2*WINDOW_H+1, 2*WINDOW_W+1, 1), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
```

should be like this:

```
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(3, kernel_size=3, padding = "same", batch_input_shape=(1, None, 2*WINDOW_H+1, 2*WINDOW_W+1, 1), stateful=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `ConvLSTM2D` layer before `Conv2D`, you use `return_sequence` is False. After you run the program, you can get the result ndim=4.